# Determining $\dim V$

Tags: vector-spaces

This is probably a simple question but I'm not sure about the answer. According to Lounesto in *Clifford Algebras and Spinors*, a vector space of $\dim V=2$ has basis such as
\begin{align}
\hat{e}_1=\left(1,0\right),\;\hat{e}_2=\left(0,1\right).
\end{align}
I can understand this as it seems the two are orthogonal (and thus are linearly independent, if I understand correctly), and if we have the Cartesian plane $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ it's easy to visualize. Now what about polar coordinates: would the basis still be the same, or would it just be understood that $\hat{e}_2=\left(0,1\right)$ means some step in angle instead of the ordinate direction on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$?

Additionally, according to Bishop and Goldberg in *Tensor Analysis on Manifolds* the dimension of a vector space $\dim V$ is determined by the maximum number of linearly independent vectors possible in that vector space. Is the basis of that vector space a reasonable way to determine the dimension, based on the number of basis associated with $V$?

Comment: Vectors written in polar coordinates are no longer vectors.  And yes, the size of an arbitrary basis is a working definition of the dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates, $(1,0)$ is a radius change and $(0,1)$ an angle shift. It is the same space, just transofrmed to a different coordinate system.

indeed, dimension of the vector space is the cardinality of its basis assuming that basis is also linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

About polar coordinates: I think it is quite impossible to see them as a basis. As first because there is not uniqueness in definition of zero, and it is needed by the definition of basis.

For the least question (probably I didn't understand): it's true that the dimension of a vector space $V$ IS the cardinality of one of its basis.

Hope this is useful.